# Sign in with Google error in script https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client

Tags: javascript, google-oauth

Started getting an error from the Google sign in script all of a sudden.

Error at _.$e in https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client

Answer (score 9):

It seems like Google has changed the type of `renderButton` `width` from `string` to `number`.

Broken:

```js
window.google.accounts.id.renderButton(button, {width: '200'});
```

Working:

```js
window.google.accounts.id.renderButton(button, {width: 200});
```

They haven't updated the documentation: https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#width

Comment: While I was able to reproduce this issue a few weeks ago, I believe it is now outdated.  Since this answer was posted, Testing `renderButton`, it now seems to work whether width is a string or a number. Also, Google has updated their documentation to change their example from `width: 400` to `width: "400"` .

Answer (score 5):

The recent update broke it if you specified the button width in a string format without the 'px' suffix.

```html
window.google.accounts.id.renderButton(button, {width: '300px'});
```

should work.

Answer (score 1):

[debug info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIz9p.png)

I debugged and found that this line of code checks that the variable 'c' must be a non-empty number type (corresponding to the 'width' parameter). Therefore, the 'width' in the second parameter of the 'google.accounts.id.renderButton' call should be of type 'number' and not 'string'.